# Continuity of embeddings and systole as you vary a metric

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry

Let $M$ be a smooth compact manifold and let $R(M)$ be the set of Riemannian metrics on $M$, topologized with the $C^\infty$ topology (viewing a metric as a section of an appropriate bundle).

I have two questions about $R(M)$, one that seems like it should be easy and the other hard.

1. Assume that $M$ has a nontrivial fundamental group and let $s:R(M) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the function that returns the systole of the metric, ie the length of the shortest non-nullhomotopic curve.  Question: Is $s$ continuous?  It feels like it should be, but I can’t seem to prove it.
2. Here is a crazier question.  Can we find some large $n$ and a continuous function from $R(M)$ to the space of smooth maps from $M$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ that takes a metric to an isometric embedding?

Comment: #1 may be easy. Given $r$ in $R(M)$, with systole $s(r)$, and $\epsilon$ in $\mathbb{R}$, take a neighborhood of $R(M)$ in which vectors change lengths by at most a factor of $1+\epsilon$. In this neighborhood, curves also change lengths by at most a factor of $1+\epsilon$, so for any $r'$ in the neighborhood $s(r')$ is within a factor of $1+\epsilon$ of $s(r)$.